# Python dictionary's value is another dictionary -- the best way?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to create a dictionary each of whose value will be another dictionary. Here is what I am doing.

```
import json
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch

conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()

all_dict = {}
whitelist = ["name", "metric", "namespace", "statistic", "comparison", "threshold", "period", "evaluation_periods", "unit", "description", "dimensions", "alarm_actions", "insufficient_data_actions", "ok_actions"]
i = 1
x = []
for alarm in alarms:
    single_dict = {}
    for attr in whitelist:
        single_dict[attr] = getattr(alarm, attr)
    all_dict[i] =  single_dict
    i = i+1
print json.dumps(all_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

It work perfectly but I feel that there might be a smarter way than what i have done.

Comment: This question might be better suitable for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); you have working code and are asking for improvements.

Comment: While you're here, though, there seems little point to having a dictionary keyed with incrementing integers rather than just a list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can have a list instead but then I am not sure how can iterate over it if I create JSON dump of the list.

Comment: @yasra002 iterate over it *where*? You can load the JSON and get the list back.

Comment: How can I do that (load JSON and get list back)? Will it be possible to recommend a link or a book that I can read regarding python which have examples.

Answer (score 0):

It might look a little neater if you used `len(all_dict)` in place of `i`. Also, it may be out of context, but I'm not sure what the `x` is doing.

Although, if the code works any changes would be purely for your education or aesthetics. Any changes would be negligible with respect to memory and processing consumption.